# masked input phone number clears textbox when i submit the page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, maskedtextbox, maskedinput

i have two issues with that:

1) i have phone format something like this:

```
$('#phone').mask('(999) 999-9999');
```

so when i submit the form i want to validate if the user has entered all 10 numbers so i tried something like this but

but somehow i am getting the mask character, how can i have just phoe number?

```
if ($('#phone').length == 10) {
    alert("10");
}
else {
   alert("not 10");
}
```

2) when i submit the form it clears the phone textbox, how can i keep the phone number in the textbox?

```
<div>
        Phone Number:
        <input id="phone" type="text" />
        (999) 999-9999
        <br />
        <div id='display'>
            error...</div>
        <input id="submitSignup" type="submit" value="Signup" /><br />
        <br />
                 </div>


$("#submitSignup").click(function (event) {

 if ($('#phone').length == 10) {
        //do something..
   }
  else {
      alert("not 10");
    }
   return; 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) i have phone format something like
>   this:

You will want `$("#phone").val().length == 10`  if you call `$('#phone').length` you are getting the number of elements matched by the jQuery selector not the value of the text box.

```
$('#phone').mask('(999) 999-9999');
$("#submitSignup").click(function(event) {
    if ($('#phone').val().length == 14) {
        alert("valid");
    }
    else {
        alert("not valid");
        return false; //stop the form to submit, also could use event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/xDx8c/1/).

Comment: tried but goes to else condition ...  `$("#phone").val().length`

Comment: when i debug i am getting `$("#phone").val().length ` = `1`

Comment: Mark: after i get the alert message it clears the textbox... how can i avoid that?

Comment: If the form is not valid you can return false, or I think you can do an event.preventDefault() instead to not allow the submit button to send the form.

Comment: @Abu, Paul is correct see updated code and fiddle that returns false if the page is not valid.